# Unexpected keyword 'type' in implementation file

Tags: f#

in VS 2008, F# 2.0, when compile a ML script have error
Unexpected keyword 'type' in implementation file

```
#indent "off" pragma

   type Hw <'o,'m>   =   cat of <'m->'o>*<'m->'o>*<'o->'m>;
```

original

```
datatype ('o,'m) Hw  =   cat of ('m->'o)*('m->'o)*('o->'m);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wanted

```
type Hw<'o,'m> = | Cat of ('m -> 'o) * ('m -> 'o) * ('o -> 'm)
```

Comment: after changed to type Cat<'o,'m>   = |  cat of ('m-> 'o) * ('m-> 'o) * ('o-> 'm) * ('m * 'm-> 'm);, got the same error

Comment: @user3277894 Because the second `cat` is lowercase.  Read your error messages.  (Also post them if you ever want help)

Comment: the error message is Unexpected keyword 'type' in implementation file, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F2D27rfQWgVEpaVnEzTTJkcVE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user3277894 - also, delete 'pragma'

Comment: Unexpected keyword 'type' in expression. Expected 'in' or other token.
Unexpected keyword 'end' in expression. Expected 'in' or other token.

Comment: Well that is completely unrealated to your original question.  The code that I have given compiles completely fine on its own